# AngularJS providers having two different receipes

Tags: angularjs

While reading up on AngularJs providers, I noticed that different authors use different receipes to descrive what AngularJS providers are.

These different receipes for defining "provider" is causing great confusion.

I have laid down the two different methods that I see in this plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZelQLtRiibH1NqetSTqe?p=info

Also, the same are given below:

```
app.provider('provider1', function(){

  this.$get = function(){
    return "value from provider1";
  }

});

app.provider('provider2', function(){

  return {
    $get: function() {
      return "value from provider2";
    }
  }

});
```

As you will notice, in "provider1", I pass what seems like a constructor function.
In "provider2", I simply return a object.

Could someone help clarify what's going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days sifting through AngularJS source code, I finally found the solution. This is not a easy one or a obvious one. One has to know the source code for the framework quiet well in order to know the reason.

While registering a provider, you have the option of simply giving a object with $get property or a constructor function with $this method. Angular will handle both differently.

The provider constructor is instantiated right when it is registered. Hence if it has any dependencies that have yet not been registered then this method will fail.

In case of provider objects, this is not a must as the $get is executed lazily.

These are not interchangeable methods and both have their own use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider), you may either provide a provider instance directly (your question is not concerned by this) or provide a constructor for the provider (both your examples do this).

The result of both your examples is essentially the same because of [how constructor functions operate in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (pay attention to the paragraph starting with *"The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole `new` expression."*).

In the first example, method(s) are assigned to the default instance object, which then becomes the instance, as the constructor doesn't return any value. In the second example, constructor returns an object containing the method(s), which then becomes the instance.